# SQL Query: Iterate through rows with same values and count occurences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

```
Name     Fruit
--------------------
Bob      Apple
Bob      Pear
Alice    Apple
Alice    Orange
Alice    Orange
Bob      Orange
Bob      Apple
Alice    Pear
Bob      Orange
Bob      Apple
```

I want to iterate through the Name column, and count the number of distinct Fruits.
The preferred output would be:

```
Name    Apple     Pear      Orange
----------------------------------
Bob     3         1         2
Alice   1         1         2
```

Does anyone know how I can write this as an SQL Query in MySQL workbench?

Comment: Does the list of possible `Fruit` column values (and so the structure of the output) is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(fruit = 'Apple') as num_apples,
       sum(fruit = 'Pear') as num_pears,
       sum(fruit = 'Orange') as num_oranges
from t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE Expression also

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fruit = 'Apple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Apples,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fruit = 'Pear' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Pear,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fruit = 'Orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Orange
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below SQL. "fruits" is name of table:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(IF(tf.Fruit = ''',
      Fruit,
      ''', 1, 0)) AS ',
      Fruit
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM fruits;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tf.name, ', 
                   @sql, 
                  ' FROM fruits tf                                     
                    GROUP BY tf.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```